# 1 bit register with data flip flop doesn't store bit?

Tags: computer-architecture, memory-hardware, storage

A 1-bit register:

[image: 1-bit register]

> Credit:
>   Elements of Computing Systems
>   by Noam Nisan and Shimon Schocken
>   ISBN-13: 978-0262640688

I know that the [data flip flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#D_flip-flop) outputs the input at the previous time step.

Based on this, I created this table (not sure if correct):

Note: For the `Mux`, 1 is for `in` and 0 is for `DFF` output.

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{In} & \text{DFF In} & \text{Load} & \text{Out} \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

The output is always alternating, no bit is being stored. It should constantly output 1 while load is 1 because that's what we initially stored.

I know that a register does actually store data, so something is wrong in my understanding of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out, the storage happens over the whole `tock (high)` of the master clock.

`t -> t+` is the `tick` and `t+ -> t+1` is the `tock`

`Load` and the `bit` we are trying to store must remain constant for at-least one whole `tock`.

So something like this:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Time} & \text{In} & \text{DFF In} & \text{Load} & \text{Out} \\ \hline
0+ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
1+ & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Your table is incorrect. A MUX element selects one of its inputs based on a secondary input. In this case it's a binary mux and `load` is used to select the input.

If we say that `load = 0` means it selects the DFF and `load = 1` means that it selects `in` you shall see that when `load = 0` the circuit repeatedly refreshes the previous value, and `load = 1` will read the new value from `in`.

Comment: Surely this would make no difference to the output, the `load` column from top to bottom would just be inverted and read `1,0,0`

Comment: @sudoman Consider the top row in your table. How can the output of the MUX be $0$ when both its inputs are $1$? I don't know your thought process behind the table so I don't know where the issue lies, but the table is simply incorrect.

Comment: Because the `DFF` outputs the previous input? right? and the previous input is nothing, so therefore `0`

Comment: @sudoman You're confused about the MUX. The circuit can take an extra cycle to stabilize if DFF has a delay, but you misunderstand the MUX. While `load = 1` the DFF does not feedback into itself.